# JavaScript/jQuery - Reusing the event 'Click' of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element, a div, for example. And attach an event 'click' to it. In jQuery, it would be:

```
 $('#myDiv').click(function(){ 
    $(".class1").show();
 })
```

Now, I would like to assign a new function "myDiv #", replacing the old. I am doing so:

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(){ 
    $(".class23").hide();
})
```

But when I run the 'click' on the div, the function I assigns the beginning of this doubt is performed.

Question: How to remove the function that will run with the click event attributed to an element? (No recreate the element with the new click event...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you'll only want to handle one click on an element, you can use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) which automatically unbinds after a single click:

```
$("#myDiv").one("click", function() {  
  $(".class1").show();
  $("#myDiv").one("click", function(){ 
    $(".class23").hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Despite the 'unbind' be a good solution, that you said offers improvements in my code.

Answer (score 4):

You want [`.unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

You can either remove all previous bound functions:

```
$('#myDiv').unbind('click');
```

Or if you only want to unbind one specific function:

```
var show = function() { 
   $(".class1").show();
};

$('#myDiv').click(show);
```

and then:

```
$('#myDiv').unbind('click', show); // unbind first function

$('#myDiv').click(function() {     // bind second function
    $(".class23").hide();
});
```

Note that `.click(func)` is just a shortcut to `.bind('click', func)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [JQuery unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function to remove all click events

```
$('#myDiv').unbind('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter on the first click event.

```
var counter = 0;
$('#myDiv').click(function(){ 
    if(counter>1){
       $(".class23").hide();
    }
    else
       $(".class1").show();

   counter++;
 })
```

just an example..